# Do F# Web frameworks exist with Websocket Secure support? (WSS) SSL

Tags: websocket, f#, web-frameworks

I am unsure if Web frameworks for F# exist that support Websocket Secure (WSS). I want to make a mobile app that communicates with an F# webserver on AWS. I want to encrypt the data.

If such a framework exists, what is the name of it?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of them is [ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/?view=aspnetcore-2.1). The framework itself isn't written in F# it does however run on the .NET Core platform, as does F#. The benefit of this is that the framework can be leveraged from F#.

The ASP.NET Core stack supports Websockets in a managed C# style. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/websockets?view=aspnetcore-2.1

ASP.Net Core is however only a small part of the ASP.NET family of frameworks. One of the common companions is ASP.Net Core MVC which is a C# oriented web framework, MVC can be leveraged from F# as well although it might not be the most natural fit for F#'s FP first style. On the same level as MVC there are other frameworks that fit into the ASP.NET Core pipeline, one such example is [Giraffe](https://github.com/giraffe-fsharp/Giraffe) which is a FP first alternative to MVC.

Higher levels of duplex communication between server and client is provided by [SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/introduction?view=aspnetcore-2.1), another ASP.NET framework.